Need formula to help cross-check values and conditions in different columns
I am hoping for help for a new challenge in my veterinary research project.  I would like a way to cross check values in different columns in my Excel spreadsheet. I want to make sure that for every case (bird) that has been assigned a category that it has at least one diagnosis (subcategory) for that category; and that no diagnoses were incorrectly assigned to a bird that didn't have that category assigned. I have 6500 cases (birds), 27 categories, and over 200 diagnoses (subcategories) and so I am hoping for a formula to help save me time and improve accuracy.




CATEGORY1
DIAGNOSIS1
DIAGNOSIS2
DIAGNOSIS3
CROSS-CHECK




BIRD1
N
N
N
N
0


BIRD2
Y
N
N
N
2


BIRD3
Y
N
N
Y
1


BIRD4
Y
Y
Y
N
1


BIRD5
N
N
Y
N
3



So in the table above, there would be two CORRECT conditions in the CROSS-CHECK (output) column: "0" and "1".

"0" would be that the particular category was not assigned to the bird (CATEGORY1="N") and no diagnosis (subcategory) for that category was assigned (DIAGNOSIS1:DIAGNOSIS3="N").
"1" would be that a category was assigned (CATEGORY1="Y") and at least one diagnosis (subcategory) was assigned (at least one column in DIAGNOSIS1:DIAGNOSIS3 contains a "Y").

There would be two ERROR conditions in the CROSS-CHECK (output) column, "2" and "3".

"2" would be that the category was assigned to the bird (CATEGORY1="Y"), but the bird was not assigned any diagnosis (subcategory) for that category (DIAGNOSIS1:DIAGNOSIS3="N")
"3" would be that the category was not assigned to the bird (CATEGORY1="N"), but at least one diagnosis (subcategory) was assigned (at least one column in DIAGNOSIS1:DIAGNOSIS3 contains a "Y")

To add to the challenge, the "N" and "Y" in the CATEGORY and DIAGNOSIS columns have been populated using LAMBDA and BYROW functions.
I have tried several formulas, some including IF(COUNTIF), but can only come up with 2 potential condition (0/1, or Y/N) for the cross-check column.  I need a more complex formula and I am having trouble writing it myself.  Additionally, because of LAMBDA/BYROW I think, I have to do a hard return to each row in the cross-check column to get it to give the correct result. I do have Microsoft 365.

=BYROW(B2:E6,LAMBDA(b,LET(c,SUM(N(DROP(b,,1)="Y"))>0,IF(TAKE(b,,1)="Y",IF(c,1,2),IF(c,3,0)))))
An if statement is used on the first column's value (IF(TAKE(b,,1)="Y"), next we check the count(/sum) of the remaining column's values equal to "Y" is greater than 0 (SUM(N(DROP(b,,1)="Y"))>0 declared as c) to get the differentiated results.
Or a bit shorter: =BYROW(B2:E6,LAMBDA(b,LET(c,OR(DROP(b,,1)="Y"),IF(@T(b)="Y",IF(c,1,2),IF(c,3,0)))))

Lauren,
P.b's solution should work. As I still use Excel 2010, I do not have access to Excel 365 functions.
I suggest the following approach:
a) create a new column "Has diagnosis" with the formula:
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:E2,"Y")=0,0,1)

b) Put in "CROSS-CHECK" column:
=IF(AND(G2=0,B2="N"),0,IF(AND(G2>0,B2="Y"),1,IF(AND(G2>0,B2="N"),3,2)))

The advantages of my approach (in my point of view)  are: 1) maintains backwards compatibility with Excel previous versions and 2) more readable code.
I tested formulas like that:


Or in one go: =IF(B2="Y",IF(AND(C2:E2="N"),2,1),IF(AND(C2:E2="N"),0,3))

Wow, this is great, I will check it out!  I like the idea of having backwards compatibility.  Thank you!

One another way, without using the LAMBDA() helper functions, and using MMULT() + XMATCH():


• Formula used in cell F2
=XMATCH(B2:B6&IF(MMULT(N(C2:E6="Y"),TOCOL(RIGHT(C1:E1))^0),"Y","N"),
 {"NN";"YY";"YN";"NY"})-1


Using MMULT() return the counts for the Diagnosis, If greater than 0 then Y else N, join with the Category Col, to create a reference and using XMATCH() to find the relative positions of the item in the array.

If there are always three columns for Diagnosis then bit shorter may be:
=XMATCH(B2:B6&IF(MMULT(N(C2:E6="Y"),{1;1;1}),"Y","N"),{"NN","YY","YN","NY"})-1



This formula converts the input to a binary then decimal value and with CHOOSE define the output value of the formula.
In CrossCheck column row 2: (and drag down)
=CHOOSE(BIN2DEC(VALUE(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF(B2:E2="N",0,1))))+1,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

With minor addition for accommodating future entries automatically (COUNTA(A:A)).
Hope your birds won't mind the rows of cats here :)


Thanks again for your help nkalvi on this other challenge with my veterinary research project, and I don't mind the cats at all!
